# Ralbag introduction of the commentary on Sefer Iyov

Tags: job-iyov-book-of, ralbag

I am looking for the introduction of the Ralbag’s commentary on Sefer Iyov. In my Mikraot Gedolot edition this introduction is skipped. I am searching for a free online edition if possible.

Comment: try these https://drive.google.com/file/d/10tUR91kjvsLk6BBXGWNDhouePH1EMCH5/view?usp=sharing and  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1--CY8ntMfQAVIvRWY8Rr7RfpUSA_HnWJ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks so much!

Comment: @rosends happy is the one who has a M"G at work !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's available on Alhatorah.org, [here](https://mg.alhatorah.org/Parshan/Ralbag_Beur_HaParashah/Iyyov/0#m7e0n6).